# Deploying thousands sites in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, orchestration

I have a e-commerce project based on Vue and Nodejs.

1 container for frontend.

1 container for backend.

I will rent this software to my customers. Instead of creating 1 instance per customer, i am thinking about deploying in kubernetes.
The problem is i couldn't solve architecture how to deploy in kubernetes but have and idea.

My idea is visualized on https://ibb.co/phqMrC8

As you can see in image i thought i pod per customer. Is this idea is good for thousands of sites and if it how can i route to correct domain to correct pod ?

Comment: Seems to me you are missing some basic concepts here... You only have nodes and pods... you should remove nodes from your equation and put services, that would make make a better vizualization...

Answer (score 0):

You should not think in terms of pods here. You should handle each *container* as a `Deployment` and *expose* each Deployment as a `Service` and then you have one or multiple `Ingress` object that your *nginx* load balancer uses (as an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/))

How many pods you have depends on the load on each container or if you want more high availability.